# Convert an unknown database file from a windows software into a MySqli Database

Tags: c++, database, firebird, vb5

I have installed a software in my system and I have a lot of data from client in it. All the files which are inside DB folder of this software are with extensions for each individual party.

I want to to use these files to get converted to a MySqli Database.

Sample file from DB folder can be download from [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=353tgd4925301049699)

I have tried understanding for firebird service which this software uses to connect with these database files to get the things.

I want to extract database and import it inside MySqli (PhpMyAdmin)

Comment: You got any example data? Would be hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried contacting CatPro?  Maybe asking if they would release their data file formats or help you out?

Comment: If the software is commercial, format is closed and not documented then probably they have a reason doing this. Try to contact the vendor and ask how much they can disclose. Just respect other's work.

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer I have added a download link to the sample DB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked file seems to be a renamed Firebird database with structure version ODS 11.2 which corresponds to Firebird 2.5.x line.

For making a quick peep into the database you can use

- IBSurgeon First Aid -- http://ib-aid.com
- IB Expert (the Database Explorer feature) -- http://ibexpert.net

Free mode of FirstAID would let you peep into the data, but not extract it out, probably not even scroll ALL the tables. It also would most probably ignore all database structures that are not tables (UDF functions, procedures, VIEWs, auto-computed columns in tables) - afterall it is just low-level format parser, not an SQL engine.

IB Expert has as a non-commercial Personal edition, but it probably does not include DB Exp, however you may try a trial period of full version. However IBE's DBExp would probably also only show basic structures of the database, maybe it would be enough.

Alternatively you can install Firebird 2.5.8 - either a standalone version or maybe embedded (a set of DLLs used instead of FB server process) if your application can use it, then use any DB IDE suit to explore it. Most often mentioned for Firebird would be IBExpert, FlameRobin, Firebird Maestro or any other. Then you would be able to try different SQL queries, including SPs, VIEWs and UDF-functions if there were any registered for the database and actually used.

BTW IBExpert comes bundled with FB 2.5 Embedded, which one can use to open the database file.

After you figure out the format, you can either export required data into some intermediate format like CSV (for example: http://fbutils.sourceforge.net/ ) or use your C++ application (though why would anyone develop web-application in C++) using libraries like IB++ or OLE DB, etc. Maybe it would be better to just use the Firebird server and original DB files from PHP or what would you write the application in.

Comment: "Sometimes it works, sometimes not..." - this brings no information to us here.... We can not imagine what can be happening in your case and thus can make no suggestions. Try www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - the text is quite harsh but it has many actionable hints.